# How to run dynamically linked ARM binaries on x86/x64 Fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, qemu, arm

I have some ARM binaries that are dynamically linked, and according to [this page](https://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation), I can install some packages for `qemu-user` to run them on my x86/x64 Linux. However, these are instructions for Debian and I am running Fedora. I tried to look for the right packages using `dnf`, and online, but have yet to find it.

How can I run dynamically linked ARM-binaries on my x64 Fedora 33?

I am getting this until now:

```
[bf@localhost src]$ file ../bin/fabs
../bin/fabs: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (ARM), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.0.0, stripped
[bf@localhost src]$ qemu-arm ../bin/fabs -V
/lib/ld-linux.so.2: Invalid ELF image for this architecture
```

When I run a simple statically linked binary, it works fine:

```
[bf@localhost src]$ file helloworld
helloworld: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (ARM), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.0.0, with debug_info, not stripped
[bf@localhost src]$ qemu-arm helloworld
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was as simple as adding the library dir of the SDK to `qemu-arm`:

```
[bf@localhost qemu]$ qemu-arm -L /usr/local/arm-linux ../bin/fabs -V
```